# Load Image in async and update table cell in main thread

Tags: asynchronous, swift4, xcode9-beta

I get the following error when I try to load images from URL in async and render them in the main thread.The app is build with Xcode9-beta.

> UIImageView.image must be used from main thread only

The images update only if I press on a cell in the tableView(and only for that particular button):

```
func updateUI(partyRock: PartyRock) {
    videoTitle.text = partyRock.videoTitle
    let url = URL(string: partyRock.imageURL)!

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            DispatchQueue.global().sync {
                self.videoPreviewImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        } catch  {
            // handle error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `DispatchQueue.global().sync` does not execute the closure in the main thread.

Comment: So how would be the correct way to update my view with the data received from the URL? any suggestion?

Comment: A very famous idiom should work: `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem